# Injective hulls of metric spaces

Tags: reference-request, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory

In the context of large scale geometry and geometric group theory, I have recently come across the concept of injective hulls of metric spaces. For a metric space $X$, let $\text{In}(X)$ be the set of all functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)+f(y) \geq  d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$ with the following additional minimality property:
If $g: X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is another function with the above property and $g \leq f$ then $g=f$.

$\text{In}(X)$ becomes a metric space when endowed with the  metric $d(f,g)=\sup \{ |f(x)-g(x)|: x \in X \}$ and is called the injective hull of $X$.

I have gone through some definitions and preliminary results about injective hulls but I don't have a good feel for the space $\text{In}(X)$. For example, I don't understand what kind of functions it can contain and what is the general idea behind its construction. I know that for every $x\in X$ the function $d_x$ given by $d_x(z)=d(x,z)$ is a member of $\text{In}(X)$ and that $z\rightarrow d_z$ is an isometric embedding of $X$ into $\text{In}(X)$.  I list below a few questions that I would like to understand:

1. If $X$ is a nice enough space, say a length space, or maybe even a Riemannian manifold, is there a nice description of the members of $\text{In}(X)$? What if we add curvature conditions, like Gromov $\delta$-hyperbolicity, or negative sectional curvature respectively?
2. Is $\text{In}(X)$ strictly bigger than $X$? What properties does $X$ need to have so that $\text{In}(X)$ is far bigger than $X$? If $X$ is compact can we expect $\text{In}(X)$ to be compact ?
3. In connection with the last question, under what conditions on $X$ is $\text{In}(X)$ "close" to $X$? In other words, when can we expect to have that $\text{In}(X)$ is a finite tubular neighbourhood of $X$ within $\text{In}(X)$?

Any help is deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The injective hull of a metric space is also called its *injective* envelope or *tight span*. Knowing this should help you search. E.g. there's [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tight_span), a [paper by Simon Willerton](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/28/22/28-22abs.html) with some examples, and a [couple](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/tight_spans_isbell_completions.html) of [blog posts](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2014/08/wrestling_with_tight_spans.html). The last few links have a categorical perspective but still address examples and the intuition.

Comment: The questions and the results about injective metric spaces, and the injective hulls were invented and developed first by Aronszajn and Panitchpakdi (1956), then by Isbell, then by Holsztyński, in 1960s. In particular, when $\ B\ $ is a Banach space, then the metric injective hull of $B$ is also the Banach injective hull (in a canonical way).

Answer (score 2):

Given a metric space $X$ and basepoint $x_0 \in X$, the Kuratowski embedding
$$x \mapsto (w \mapsto d(x,w)-d(x_0,w))$$
provides an isometric embedding $\Theta$ of $X$ into the injective space $\ell^\infty(X)$. However, $\ell^\infty(X)$ is usually huge compared to the image of the embedding $\Theta$. The key point is that the smallest injective subspace of $\ell^\infty(X)$ containing $\Theta(X)$ is canonical and can be described explicitly by exhibiting a specific family of functions in $\ell^\infty(X)$.

In general, however, having a good understanding of the injective hull of a metric space is very difficult.

1. For hyperbolic spaces, there is a nice description of their injective hulls. This is a work of Urs Lang, [arxiv:1107.5971](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5971).
2. Due to the fact that the injective hull is canonical, $X$ is properly contained in its injective hull precisely when $X$ is not itself injective.
3. It is proved in [arxiv:2002.06895](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06895) that $X$ is quasi-dense in its injective hull iff $X$ is coarsely injective, i.e. there exists some $\delta$ such that, for every finite collection of pairwise intersecting balls $B(x_i,r_i)$, the intersection $\bigcap B(x_i,r_i+\delta)$ is non-empty.

If you want to learn more about injective metric spaces from the perspective of geometric group theory, you can take a look at Thomas Haettel's notes [Group actions on injective spaces and Helly graphs](https://arxiv.org/abs/2307.00414).